# C++ Functions from class not performing?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, function, class

I'm trying and learning classes, and I wanted this basic project (Polish Reverse Notation Calculator) to work inside of it. I can make it work in separated voids / ints, but when I tried to put it into classes, it is compiling but program exits immediately, like nothing was there. What am I missing? I really want to know what is wrong...

```
void appMenu::mainMenu()
{
    int choice;

    cout << "Extended Reverse Polish Notation calculator\n"
         << "Actions to perform: \n"
         << "   1. Input your operations. \n "
         << "   2. Load operations from file. \n"
         << "   3. Exit." << endl;

    cout << "What action do you want to perform?" << endl;
    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == '1')
    {
        appMenu calcFromInput();
    }

    /*  else if (choice == '2')
    {
        appMenu calcFromFile();
    } */

    else if (choice == '3')
    {
        exit(0);
    }

    else appMenu MainMenu();
}
```

Pastebin code:    `https://pastebin.com/Cp9VW97U`

Comment: You don't need to prefix your function calls with `appMenu`. Also, you're comparing an `int` (`choice`) to a `char` instead of another `int` (e.g. `choice == '1'`)?

Comment: `appMenu calcFromInput();` declares a function and essentially does nothing; not create an object. and the final `else` has the same problem. The code being wrong is the only reason `appMenu MainMenu()` likely compiled, because you probably meant `mainMenu`, not `MainMenu`.

Comment: create an object of `appMenu` as `appMenu appM;`, and then call the function `MainMenu()` with object created `appM.MainMenu()` , as per the code in pastebin, this should be called as : 
`appMenu appM;
appM.MainMenu();`

Comment: @Venkata Vamshi - thanks, that was it. Than you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
appMenu calcFromInput();
```

This line doesn't do anything at runtime. It declares a function (*i.e. tells that compiler that a function exists*) named `calcFromInput()` that returns an object of type `appMenu`. If you meant to call this function, it's just this:

```
calcFromInput();
```

Likewise with this

```
appMenu MainMenu();
```

Comment: @Sheerley: Are you sure? Does it say `mainMenu`? Or does it say `MainMenu`?